# Multiple CoGroupByKey with same key apache beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow, apache-beam

I have a situation where I need to join the main data stream (1.5TB) in my pipeline to 2 different datasets (4.92GB and 17.35GB).  The key that I use to do the CoGroupByKey for both are the same.  Is there a way to avoid reshuffling the left side of the join after the first completes?  Currently I am just leaving the output as a KV>.  This seems to be better than emitting each element piecewise after the first join, but the second groupByKey still seems to be taking a lot longer than I would expect.  I was going to start looking into pulling apart CoGroupByKey to see if I can ignore grouping one side, but I really feel safer not going down to that level at this point.

[This was prior to keeping Iterables grouped after the first join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WD37U.png)

Comment: CoGroupByKey supports an arbitrary number of input collections. Would it be possible to key all 3 input collections the same, and do a single CoGroupByKey rather than 2 in sequence?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered accessing the smaller datasets as `View.asMap()` or `View.asMultimap()` side inputs when processing the main input? The Dataflow runner has an optimized implementation of map and multimap side inputs which performs key lookups efficiently without loading the whole data into memory.

Comment: Unfortunately my smallest of the PCollections is around 5GB. From what I understand that it way too big for a side input

Comment: I had never noticed the `--workerCacheMB` option in the docs before.  Is this what you are referring to?  If so, would you mind taking a stab at what I ought to set this to as a start to testing?

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/par-do#side-inputs

Comment: Side inputs can be arbitrarily large - there is no limit; we have seen pipelines successfully run using side inputs of 1+TB in size. The workerCacheMB option affects only performance (cache hit rate) in case the side input is accessed many times by the same worker. I suggest you do not set this option at all (assume the default value) and give it a try, and write back in case performance is unsatisfactory.

Comment: Ok great!  I'll work on that conversion now.  My pipeline in general will be a lot simpler if I can get these to work efficiently as Side Inputs. Thanks for the direction!

Comment: @chillerm What was the result, and how's the beard doing?

Comment: @successhawk Haha, it's back within standards (unfortunately).  It was some bad code on my part where I was basically recreating a list of right side elements and attaching to each of the left side elements instead of creating the right side once.  As for the large side input, I only tried it a couple times, but I haven't seen an improvement using that method.  The shuffle service on the other hand is incredible.  I'll see if I can share some of those numbers.